# Integer variable's value changes after passing to a function in c++

Tags: c++, variables, segmentation-fault, parameter-passing

I am passing the value of the int variable N in the function func in the code given below. But after the func is executed the value of N changes.
I am passing N by value. Can somebody help me out? Why is the value changing?

```
void sort_by_pivot(int ar[], int N, int p)
{
    int pivot = ar[p],temp;
    for(int i=0; i<p; i++)
    {
        while(ar[i]>pivot)
        {
            if(ar[i] > pivot)
            {
                ar[p] = ar[p-1];
                ar[p-1] = pivot;
                temp = ar[i];
                ar[i] = ar[p];
                ar[p] = temp;
                p--;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=p+1; i<N; i++)
    {
        while(ar[i]<pivot)
        {
            if(ar[i] < pivot && p<N)
            {
                ar[p] = ar[p+1];
                ar[p+1] = pivot;
                temp = ar[i];
                ar[i] = ar[p];
                ar[p] = temp;
                p++;
            }
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    int ar[] = {5,9,2,6,1,4,3,7,8};

    int N = 9;
    int p = 4;

    printf("%d\n",N);
    sort_by_pivot(ar, N, p);

    printf("%d\n",N);
}
```

Here's the output:

```
9
1
```

Comment: Move `int N` and `int p` to before your array declaration; I bet you get a different result (with your compiler).

Comment: I get 9 then a seg fault when I run your code.

Comment: BTW: Why not add const specifiers?

Comment: You have no bounds checking, and in the 2nd loop the `p` variable will be increased to beyond the length of the actual array, resulting in memory corruption, and undefined behavior. Your algorithm is broken. The End.

Comment: Please show your call.

Comment: This isn't a question for SO. Not until you've read and applied the material in [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You need to do your part in this first. Only then, if you don't understand what's causing the problem you uncovered, you'll be able ask here, with a [mcve].

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am getting the same result after moving them before array declaration. btw I am using g++ 7.2.0.

Comment: I run your code here and it doesn't happen

Output:
9
9

Comment: @Corvo Do you have valgrind of clang installed? Compiling with clang's sanitizer options or checking your program with valgrind would help you understand those errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the described problem is a clear indication of memory corruption, i.e. the code overwrites some memory that it doesn't own. In this case it overwrites the value of `N` in `main`.

The problem is when your sort function reach p=1 and i=0. Assume the list look like

```
{9, 1, ....}
```

These lines

```
            ar[p] = ar[p-1];
            ar[p-1] = pivot;
```

change the list to

```
{1, 9, ....}
```

Then you do

```
            temp = ar[i];
            ar[i] = ar[p];
            ar[p] = temp;
            p--;
```

so the list is (by mistake) changed back to

```
{9, 1, ....}
```

and p becomes 0.

Therefore you'll do one more loop where you write to `ar[p-1]` which is now `ar[-1]`, i.e. out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks man!!!                                                                                                                     Best answer and on point.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading and writing `ar[p-1]`, when p can be (and in this case *is*) zero. Reading or writing outside the bounds of an array is **Undefined Behavior.**

Comment: when p will reach zero the the while loop will not run bcoz in that case ar[p] == pivot. anyways, I just want to know why is N being modified here outside the function.

Comment: @Corvo: 1) `p` reaches 0 in the first `while` loop, if you don't believe me *print it out*. 2) You do not test `ar[p]` against `pivot`, you test `ar[i]` against `pivot`. 3) **Undefined behavior** can modify variables outside the function that causes it -- or anything else it wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is incorrect.

You are crossing boundaries of array `ar` smashing memory. You never check the value of the index `p+1` and `p-1` inside the  `while(ar[i]>pivot)` and  `while(ar[i]<pivot)` loops.  If `p+1 >= N` or `p-1 < 0` you have a problem.

Comment: `ar` has type `int[9]`, `N=9`, so `ar[N]` certainly is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Caninonos Thank you for your comment! Good catch! Corrected.

Comment: when p will reach zero the the while loop will not run bcoz in that case ar[p] == pivot. anyways, I just want to know why is N being modified here outside the function.

Comment: @Corvo You are writing past the `ar[]` array overwriting the `N` variable. Both  `ar[]`  and `N` are located on the on stack and quite likely located side by side in the memory.